# jQuery matching: How do I select blocks of content that has a forward slash in its opening tag?

Tags: jquery, regex, handlebars.js

Using handlebars.js, I'm trying to use jQuery to select all content loops that has a forward slash in its opening tag. For example, I have these loops in my HTML:

```
{{#each /stackoverflow-string-a}}
  contentA
{{/each}}

<h3>More content</h3>
{{#each /stackoverflow-string-b}}
  contentB
{{/each}}
```

I want to use a jQuery selector to select the content inside all loops with a forward slash like so:

```
var content_from_all_loops_with_a_forward_slash = ???????;
$(content_from_all_loops_with_a_forward_slash);

=> ["contentA", "contentB"]
```

What regex matching string should I use? That is, how should I define "content_from_all_loops_with_a_forward_slash" to retrieve'["contentA", "contentB"]'?

Comment: What template language is being used to generate the looped elements?  HTML doesn't have an '#each' tag ;)

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry! I'm using handlebars.js :)